# mobile devices unable to read my cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, device

Trying to simply have a popup display once per user session (our restaurant will be closed for a private event)... 
when the user clicks on another page on our site, the popup would once again popup... I didn't like this... So I did this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("naniCOOKIE=") == -1) {
    var now = new Date();
    document.cookie = "naniCOOKIE=yes";

    function Landing() {
      $lb.launch({
        url: "special_notice.php",
        options: "width:570px height:110px",
        title: " ",
        description: ""
      });
    }
  }
</script>
```

and it works great on all pc's mac's etc... Just not on mobile devices!! It will always popup... and I don't want that... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your code here is right? The Landing function is never called.

Comment: i should be a bit more detailed... 
 
every page has: <body onLoad="Landing()" text="#ffffff" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" >

i have a header.php that includes:
<?php include('variables.php'); ?>
<?=$closed_notice;?>

inside variables is: 

$closed_notice = '<script type="text/javascript">
 if (document.cookie.indexOf("naniCOOKIEE=") == -1) {
var now = new Date();
document.cookie = "naniCOOKIEE=yes";
 function Landing() {
$lb.launch({
url: "special_notice.php",
options: "width:570px height:110px",

});
}
}
</script>';

Answer (score 0):

Defining the Landing function only if the cookie isn't present is not a great solution because (if working as intended) an error will happen when the page tries to call the Landing function when it hasn't been defined.

Additionally, it's a bad strategy because it's not supported by Javascript (ES5), and it's only working in some browsers because of nonstandard behavior. Function declarations aren't supposed to be in non-function blocks like an if-block. Some browsers (such as the mobile devices you've tried) will hoist the function declaration up and out of the if-block.

Here's a good way to fix both problems, so that it doesn't rely on nonstandard behavior and doesn't ever leave Landing undefined. Instead of only sometimes defining the function, just move the conditional check into the function:

```
function Landing() {
  if (document.cookie.indexOf("naniCOOKIE=") == -1) {
    var now = new Date();
    document.cookie = "naniCOOKIE=yes";

    $lb.launch({
      url: "special_notice.php",
      options: "width:570px height:110px",
      title: " ",
      description: ""
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much for responding and tweaking my code.. i changed it to what you suggested.. works as it should with desktop OS, but the popup is still happening on every page load with the ipad i just tested on..

Comment: NEVER MIND! nix that!!! it is working perfectly!!! very strange, i had cleared the IPADS cache and history.. closed safari, and tested, and it was still popping up on every page! then i hit refresh on safari, and TADA! it worked.. i would go to pages, and no popups! thank you so much for you help! i spent hours trying to figure it out myself! thank you thank you!